# How do I successfully combine these two paramaterized equations?

Tags: parametric

I'm working on a set of equations that would tell a hypothetical robot soccer player whether or not to pass a ball to a teammate. After a lot of algebra, I arrived at these equations for the partial boundary of a region:

$$x=v_1t_{\alpha}\cos\left(90-\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{v_2^2t_{\alpha}^2-v_1^2t_{\alpha}^2-d_{\Sigma}}{2v_1t_{\alpha}d_{\Sigma}}\right)\right)$$

$$y=v_1t_{\alpha}\sin\left(90-\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{v_2^2t_{\alpha}^2-v_1^2t_{\alpha}^2-d_{\Sigma}}{2v_1t_{\alpha}d_{\Sigma}}\right)\right)$$

They are equations for $x$ and $y$, respectively, parameterized by time ($t_{\alpha}$).

How do I go about writing $x$ as a function of $y$? I'm looking for hints, not full solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:
I am using your "90"
(measuring angles in degrees)
instead of 
the more usual
"$\pi/2$"
(radian measure).

Since the args of the 
$\sin$ and $\cos$
look the same,
you have
$x = A \cos(u),
y=A \sin(u)$
for appropriate
$A$ and $u$.
Therefore
$x^2+y^2
=A^2
$.

Also,
since
$\sin(v)
=\cos(90-v)
$,
$90-\cos^{-1}(x)
=\sin^{-1}(x)
$,
so the second term
is
$\sin(\sin^{-1}(v))
= v
$,
so this gives 
$y$ as a function
without trig functions.

Similarly,
you can use
$\cos(\sin^{-1}(x))
=\sqrt{1-x^2}
$
to eliminate the trig functions
from the first equation.

Comment: That's incredibly simple. Thank you.